# Reconfigure Samsung Galaxy Note 4 Fingerprint Scanner

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-4

Is there a way to avoid clicking on the centre button where the fingerprint scanner is. I would like to reconfigure the fingerprint scanner to go to home when brushed. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not without rooting the phone, no.

Comment: That means, the answer is actually, "Yes, if you're rooted". Meanwhile, could you provide the steps/reference to do this on rooted device?

Comment: And any apps that do that when rooted? Am I the only one annoyed (and lazy) by the clicking

Comment: No, my wording was precise. Without root it's not possible. With root it MAY be possible, but I'm unable to locate any appropriate apps to do so, and I suspect it's not. In reality, I don't believe there are any capacitive sensors in that button, so without pressing it, it's unaware that you're interacting with it.